# How to prove that there are only 7 numbers satisfying the equation number = (sum of its digits) * (sum of its digits squared)^2?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been struggling to solve this problem for several days already. The problem reads as follows:

> Find all non-zero numbers that are equal to the sum of its digits multiplied by the sum of the squares of its digits squared, and then prove there exists only 7 of them. One of such numbers is $2023 = (2 + 0 + 2 + 3) \cdot (2^2 + 0^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)^2$.

I managed to find the numbers using brute force algorithm, however I cannot seem to find any correlation between those numbers whatsoever.
Here are the numbers:
**1
2023
2400
52215
615627
938600
1648656**

Comment: please don't use boldface for major portions of your question. If you want to highlight the main question, use blockquote. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that the community understands your question clearly.

Comment: You can use the fact that if $X$ has $n$ digits then $X \leq (9)_n$ where $(9)_n$ is the decimal natural number consisting of $n$ digits all equal to $9$. Calculate the RHS for this number, and if $X$ satisfies that equation then $X$ is at most the value of the RHS at $(9)_n$. This leads to a simple bound on $n$. The rest, unfortunately, must probably be done by the computer, modulo (perhaps!) some last-digit constraints?

Comment: That's true, it's quite easy to find some strong constraints for a harshad number that is divisible by a square, but the fact that it was given to me by my maths professor makes me wonder if there exists a beautiful solution to this problem.

Comment: What about 2400? The sum of the square of the digits is congruent to 2 mod 9

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer What is a concrete upper bound for a number having the desired property ?

Comment: @Peter If the number has 9 digits, then the product can be at most $9^8=43,046,721$, which is less than all 9-digit numbers. Therefore such a number must be less than $10^8$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the left side is $v \in [10^{n-1},10^n-1]$, then the right side $\le (9n)(9^2n)^2=9^5n^3$.

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{10^{x-1}}{9^5x^3}$. When $n\ge 9$, then $f(n) > 1$. It means $10^{n-1} > 9^5n^3$.

So when $n \ge 9$, the left side is always larger than the right side. You only need to check when $n < 9$.

It's limited and small for the computer. You can use the computer to check every number less than $10^{9-1}$.

Then it is proved.